# Uiautomatorviewer.bat is not opening

Tags: automation, appium, android-uiautomator

```
Question:

I am trying to use Uiautomator, but I am encountering some errors that prevent it from opening. How can I solve this issue?

Image of the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGnHr.png)
```

Uiautomator is not opening showing error. Please help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWsJr.png)